# Why is CloudFront not forwarding query strings when using route parameters?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

An HTTP API with two routes:

`/route1`

`/route2/{param}`

Using a CloudFront cache policy with `myquery` query string included:

when calling `/route1?myquery=foo` - the query string is available in the lambda payload,

when calling `/route2/something?myquery=foo` - the query string is missing from the payload.

When calling the API directly, without CloudFront, the query string is always in the payload.

Why is that?

Comment: Can you try adding a trailing slash before query parameters like this `/route2/something/?myquery=foo`? Also if possible share the caching policies you defined in the CloudFront.

Comment: @ArpitJain I tried with a slash '/' before the query parameter, but the response is 404. I also tried with different cache policy settings, with no effect.